# unable to write a command to a file

Tags: bash, shell

Unable to send an echo statement to a file , any help ? Currently I see the o/p coming for code `free -k` but none of the `echo` statements are coming .

I have tested with multiple echo statements and none are working.

```
#!/bin/bash
#--------Check for Memory Utilization--------#
set -x
ScriptName="${0##*/}"
LogTime=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
LogDate=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")
FinalLogName="$ScriptName"_"$LogDate".log
touch "$FinalLogName"
echo "running test log" > "$FinalLogName"
echo "running testing log at $LogTime" > "$FinalLogName"
echo "running for script $ScriptName " > "$FinalLogName"
echo "running the script $ScriptName at $LogTime" > "$FinalLogName"
free -k > /tmp/memutil.log| tee "$FinalLogName" ; sed -n -e 2,3p -e 4p /tmp/memutil.log| tee "$FinalLogName"
rm /tmp/memutil.log
```

I expect the output to print all the echo statements with `free -k` command info.

Comment: After `free -k > /tmp/memutil.log` all output (except stderr)  is written to `/tmp/memutil.log`. The remaining output (nothing) is piped into `tee`, and `tee` will write it (nothing) to the stdout (terminal) and the "$FinalLogName" (making it empty). You might want to use `tee -a` for append in `free -k | tee -a "$FinalLogName" > /tmp/memutil.log`, but I am not sure what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirecting with `>` overwrites the file. And so does `tee` by default. To make an appending redirect use `>>` and the `-a` flag for `tee`.

```
#!/bin/bash
#--------Check for Memory Utilization--------#
set -x
ScriptName="${0##*/}"
LogTime=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
LogDate=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")
FinalLogName="$ScriptName"_"$LogDate".log
touch "$FinalLogName"
echo "running test log" >> "$FinalLogName"
echo "running testing log at $LogTime" >> "$FinalLogName"
echo "running for script $ScriptName " >> "$FinalLogName"
echo "running the script $ScriptName at $LogTime" >> "$FinalLogName"
free -k > /tmp/memutil.log| tee -a "$FinalLogName" ; sed -n -e 2,3p -e 4p /tmp/memutil.log| tee -a "$FinalLogName"
rm /tmp/memutil.log
```

Comment: Such a small thing , how did i miss :(